# Selenium C# ITakesScreenshot timed out while trying to take a screenshot in catch block

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, screenshot

I am having an issue while trying to take screenshot upon test failure. I get timed out error when try to take the screenshot on failure condition. It works fine in try block but timed out in catch block. Any help would be appreciate.

Below is the method to take screenshot:

```
 public class Logging
        {
           public static void ErrorScreenshot()
            {
                //Take the screenshot
                Screenshot ssh = ((ITakesScreenshot)Driver.BrowserInstance).GetScreenshot();
                //Save the screenshot
                 ssh.SaveAsFile("C:/Users/", ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
             } 
          }
```

This is my test method

```
    public static bool FindElement
    {
      get
      {
          try
          {
             var element = Driver.BrowserInstance.FindElement(By.XPath("  "));
             if (element != null)
             {
               return true;
             }
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
             Logging.ErrorScreenshot();
             Logging.Error("Not able to find element" + ex.ToString());
          }
          return false;
     }

  }
```

when it is not able to find the element it goes to catch block and there Logging.ErrorScreenshot method throws a timed out exception.

```
Error details:
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:55418/session/f3dbde1645dd91e453c5823d72199ea9/screenshot timed out after 60 seconds.
  Source=WebDriver
  StackTrace:
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.GetScreenshot()
   at AvbLinqAutoFramework.Logging.ErrorScreenshot() in C:\Users\Logging.cs:line 66
   at DashboardPage.get_Verifylogin() in C:\Users\DasboardPage.cs:line 65
   at Tests() in C:\Users\SmokeTests\Tests.cs:line 33

Inner Exception 1:
WebException: The operation has timed out
```

Comment: What is the original exception? Can you move the line that logs the exception above the screenshot line and post what the original exception was?

Comment: @GregBurghardt thank you for pointing me towards the right direction. This is how I had originally that the line logs the exception above the screenshot but didn't think the issue could be original exception. Since I am using XPath contains which was actually timing out. I have used another selector  and works fine.

Comment: Ok. Hm. I was just hoping the original exception could point us to the real problem. Although if the original exception was a timeout, then it means Selenium lost its connection to the browser. And without a connection to the browser you can't take a screenshot. You might be trying to solve the wrong problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue by using different selector (CssSelector) and WebDrverWait. The original exception was timing out while not able to find the element using XPath.

```
public static bool FindElement
        {
            get
            {
                try
                {
       WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.BrowserInstance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
var inputspcmodel = wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector($"div[id ='modelSearch-container'] div[class='k-widget k-multiselect k-multiselect-clearable'] div input")));
inputspcmodel.Click();
return true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Logging.Error("Not able to find element " + ex.ToString());
                    Logging.ErrorScreenshot();
                }
                return false;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Your CSS selector doesn't look much like a CSS selector... it looks more like XPath syntax. I would change it to `#modelSearch-container div.k-widget.k-multiselect.k-multiselect-clearable div input`. It makes it easier to read but also removes the exact string comparison for class. `#` indicates an ID and `.` indicates a class name.

Comment: Also, your `FindElement` method is clicking which seems odd given the name. You might want to change that it to make it more clear what the method is actually doing. If you are using a library like NUnit, you can wait until the end of the test, check to see if the test failed, and if so then take a screenshot. That will make sure you get a screenshot of *every* failure without having to put your code in all possible places in addition to `FindElement`

Comment: @JeffC thank you for the feedback. I will clean the CSS Selector. FindElement method name was just a 'test method name' when I started this test. I've changed it to actual meaningful name.